# Second monitor goes black when joined on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a MSU GE63VR 7RE (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz) and a 24" Acer monitor

When I start Ubuntu, the second monitor is black but I can see the mouse arrow.

When I turn the monitor off and on it is mirrored but the picture is frozen, the mouse appears on the second screen but the picture does not update.

When I attempt to join the second screen goes blank.

I find it almost impossible to work with one screen, any idea where I can start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reinstalled ubuntu but this time selected the download option and also the third part install option.

After booting, I followed the guide here : 
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

As you can see the guide is out of date, however ignoring that, I followed guide and ran

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The second monitor is now working perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Just updating drivers worked for me too. Not reinstallation required.

Comment: Worked for me as well thanks! No need to reinstall. Just make sure you reboot after!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on a Dell Precision with a Nvidia gpu and Ubuntu 20.04. It turns out that the nvidia-drivers-460 wasn't correctly installed, and there was a problem with nvidia-dkms-460.

Using the servers version of the drivers instead of the base versions solved the problem :  software -> additional drivers -> use the NVIDIA Server driver.